# Do C compilers de-duplicate (merge) code?

Tags: c, optimization, compilation

Loop unrolling is a common optimization, but is the reverse done too?
*(to reduce size of the object file output, a smaller binary).*

I'm curious if it's a common technique for compilers to de-duplicate successive, identical blocks of code (or function calls) into a loop, or extract a duplicate block into a static function.

I'm interested because there are header-only libraries`*` in C which can add a lot of duplicate code, so it would be useful to know if some C compilers are able to detect this and handle it more efficiently.

`*` *By header-only-library, I mean a header that defines code directly rather than function definitions.*

And if this is done, it would be useful to know under what conditions & constraints apply to ensure it can be made use of.

Note (For the purpose of the question - any popular C compiler is fine GCC/Clang/Intel/MSVC).

A header-only library I found, called **uthash** uses some very large macros, and I wanted to know if there was some compiler trickery going on that could cleverly de-duplicate such huge blocks of code, see: eg [uthash.h](https://github.com/troydhanson/uthash/blob/master/src/uthash.h), another similar example is [inline qsort.h](http://www.corpit.ru/mjt/qsort.html)

---

Example of a block that could be de-duplicated (it turns out `Py_DECREF` can expand into a fairly large block of code).

```
#define PY_ADD_TO_DICT(dict, i)  \
    do {
        PyDict_SetItemString(dict, names[i], item = PyUnicode_FromString(values[i])); \
        Py_DECREF(item); \
    } while (0)

/* this could be made into a loop */
PY_ADD_TO_DICT(d, 0);
PY_ADD_TO_DICT(d, 1);
PY_ADD_TO_DICT(d, 2);
PY_ADD_TO_DICT(d, 3);
```

*Note, this is contrived, but based on a real example.*

---

### Clarification

It seems the short answer to my question is **no** (or only in some limited / trivial cases), just to clarify why I was asking a bit further.

Some replies in comments seem to assume anyone you would just refactor code into a function.
This is **almost-always** the best option of course, nevertheless there are times when blocks of very similar code can show up.

- boiler plate code created by a not-very-smart code generator.
- when using an external API which exposes some of its functionality as macros *(in this case wrapping locally in functions works in most cases of course, but this means your code gets its own quirks which aren't typical for uses of those API's)*.
- when you can't replace macros with functions, there are some rare cases where it just ends up being impractical to do this.
- when importing code from an external code-base, its not always ideal to go in and start cleaning up their code, when evaluating that code-base its useful to have an idea how smart the compiler will be at optimizing the code.

In all these cases its possible to de-duplicate *(generate smarter code, wrap macros in functions, patch 3rd party libraries)*, but before going making an effort to do such things its worth knowing how much work the compiler is doing for us.

Comment: *"I'm curious if its a common technique for compilers to de-duplicate code, into a loop,"* I don't understand what you mean by "de-duplicate code into a loop"?  Are you asking if the compiler would take multiple, similar statements, allocate an array, push all of the same type but different variables into it, and iterate over that array?  No... it won't.  Why would it?  What do you consider "duplicate code" exactly?  The constraints on the compiler are defined by the standard.

Comment: Clarified the question, as for why-would-it? Well you might be using gcc with `-Os`, and have a macro instantiated 100's of times. Its possible the compiler could extract that into a static function under certain conditions.

Comment: I think he's asking about a generalization of common sub-expression elimination, but applying it to whole statements or blocks of code.

Comment: @ideasman42 If the programmer thought it would be better as a function, why didn't they just write a function and have the macro call it?

Comment: The compiler doesn't even see macros.  Expanding macros is the job of the pre-processor.  Perhaps you could add an example?

Comment: @Ed S. right - the point is that the blocks of code may be identical, so there is at least some opportunity for the compiler to be smart here.

Comment: compilers definitely remove useless code, but factorization doesnt seem like something i would guess they do at all.

Comment: Deduplicate is probably the wrong word.  Maybe merge?

Comment: I would doubt that most compilers spend much time doing this.  They're way better off leaving the code the way it is and eliminating the common subexpressions.

Comment: if you want loop, `for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)PY_ADD_TO_DICT(d, i);` I don't understand your question

Comment: I've certainly seen CSE used to merge identical case clauses in switch statements. But I don't know that I've ever seen factoring of case clauses...

Comment: Compilers can certainly eliminate effect-free code, and they will deduce constraints on variable values to reason about possible execution paths, but compiler writers focus on helping improve the results for at least reasonably mindful code.

Comment: @Bryan Chen, of course its simple to do this manually, however its useful to know what the compiler can do for us, Theres the case of generated code, or using macros from a 3rd party which may pull in many lines of code.

Comment: Added reference to https://github.com/troydhanson/uthash/blob/master/src/uthash.h - check this to better understand why one might be interested in compiler de-duplication.

Comment: No, compiler writers don't waste their time on things that take large effort with virtually no benefit. If you're hot to reduce the memory footprint of your code, wrap the macro in a function.

Comment: The concept of pulling code out of line and into a method is known as "method extraction".  This is commonly done when manually refactoring code, and way back when (1970s) some compilers attempted to do it automatically (because storage was so expensive), but modern compilers get far more mileage going the other way and inlining methods.

Comment: @Hot Licks, do you have a reference? - this could be a good answer.

Comment: If you mean compilers that attempted method extraction, no.  I only recall it being discussed, probably about 1985.

Comment: A compiler that "de-unrolled" this back into a loop would be unpopular because people write code this way because they want the loop to be unrolled.

Comment: @raymond-chen - only if it were applied globally, limits could be used (as with inlining), to avoid over-zealous behavior.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Depending on the toolchain, you may have options to coach the compiler and linker into recognizing and coalescing redundant code.  Some good google keywords include:

- "code factoring" [and additional keywords](http://www.rowleydownload.co.uk/avr/documentation/index.htm?http://www.rowleydownload.co.uk/avr/documentation/hld_option_optimize_code_factoring.htm)
- "whole program optimization"
- "interprocedural optimization" [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization)
- "link time optimization" [LTO](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/LTO.html#LTO)

Note that the [gcc optimizations page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) mentioned in previous comments provides some flags of interest, namely:

- -ftree-tail-merge
- -ftree-switch-conversion
- -fgcse
- -fcrossjumping
- -fipa-pta
- -fipa-icf *(identical code folding), added in GCC5.x*
- -fopa-cp
- -flto
- -fwhole-program

Finally, these blog posts are informative:

- http://hubicka.blogspot.com/2014/04/linktime-optimization-in-gcc-1-brief.html
- http://hubicka.blogspot.com/2014/04/linktime-optimization-in-gcc-2-firefox.html

Answer (score 5):

What might be the easiest way to describe this is referred to as refactoring code. This is the sort of thing you could do by hand as the developer, but this is not a feature of modern C compilers and optimizers, at least as far as GCC is conncerned. Included below is a list of all the individual optimizations you can set (via `-O0` and `-O2`, respectively) in GCC, for example, and none of them refactor a series of similar statements to use a common index in a loop.

```
 Optimization Level Zero              Optimization Level Two
 ============================================================================================================
 -fauto-inc-dec                       -fthread-jumps 
 -fbranch-count-reg                   -falign-functions  -falign-jumps 
 -fcombine-stack-adjustments          -falign-loops  -falign-labels 
 -fcompare-elim                       -fcaller-saves 
 -fcprop-registers                    -fcrossjumping 
 -fdce                                -fcse-follow-jumps  -fcse-skip-blocks 
 -fdefer-pop                          -fdelete-null-pointer-checks 
 -fdelayed-branch                     -fdevirtualize -fdevirtualize-speculatively 
 -fdse                                -fexpensive-optimizations 
 -fforward-propagate                  -fgcse  -fgcse-lm  
 -fguess-branch-probability           -fhoist-adjacent-loads 
 -fif-conversion2                     -finline-small-functions 
 -fif-conversion                      -findirect-inlining 
 -finline-functions-called-once       -fipa-cp 
 -fipa-pure-const                     -fipa-sra 
 -fipa-profile                        -fisolate-erroneous-paths-dereference 
 -fipa-reference                      -foptimize-sibling-calls 
 -fmerge-constants                    -foptimize-strlen 
 -fmove-loop-invariants               -fpartial-inlining 
 -fshrink-wrap                        -fpeephole2 
 -fsplit-wide-types                   -freorder-blocks -freorder-blocks-and-partition -freorder-functions 
 -ftree-bit-ccp                       -frerun-cse-after-loop  
 -ftree-ccp                           -fsched-interblock  -fsched-spec 
 -fssa-phiopt                         -fschedule-insns  -fschedule-insns2 
 -ftree-ch                            -fstrict-aliasing -fstrict-overflow 
 -ftree-copy-prop                     -ftree-builtin-call-dce 
 -ftree-copyrename                    -ftree-switch-conversion -ftree-tail-merge 
 -ftree-dce                           -ftree-pre 
 -ftree-dominator-opts                -ftree-vrp 
 -ftree-dse                           -fuse-caller-save
 -ftree-forwprop                
 -ftree-fre                     
 -ftree-phiprop                 
 -ftree-sink                    
 -ftree-slsr                    
 -ftree-sra                     
 -ftree-pta                     
 -ftree-ter                     
 -funit-at-a-time
```

**References**

---

1. *3.10 - Options that control optimization*, Accessed 2014-07-07, [`<https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html>`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)

Comment: I often wish this feature existed though.  Also for switches.  I find my company's code has a lot of switches where the body of each `case` is identical except for some value.  These should have been a table, but I don't think the compiler is smart enough to figure that out.

Comment: @MooingDuck Makes me wonder why they need a `switch` instead of a single `if-else`.

Comment: because these blocks can have literally thousands of case statements: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff4e7a32e6696c2c

Answer (score 3):

Although it seems to be very doable, I have never seen any optimization which will take two similar pieces of code and combine them into a single loop.

However, there are two cases of duplication which *are* removed by the compiler (most obviously, because there's also a performance gain, not just a code size gain):

1. When two expression evaluate to the same value, in the same function, a technique called [common subexpression elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) removes the redundant computations.
   Interestingly, with aggressive inlining and link-time optimization more and more cases could be covered by this - but of course inlining has its own severe binary size cost.
2. When it's possible to vectorize the code, a [vectorizing compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(parallel_computing)) can often identify that and do the vectorization for you.

Other than that, you'll have to manually refactor the code to remove duplication.

Comment: Didn't you mean "refactor the code to remove *duplication*." in last sentence?